# Client-access to Windows 7 CIFS shares when configured as VPN host

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking, vpn, file-sharing

I have a Win7 box configured as a VPN server using the built-in Windows VPN service and all the appropriate fwd/passthru configs applied in the gateway.  Connecting to the VPN works.

However, VPN clients cannot access file shares stored on the VPN host.  Clients *can* access file shares from any other Windows or Linux (samba) clients on the VPN host's network.

```
                     [PC1]
                       |
[VPN CLIENT] ---> [VPN HOST PC]
                       |
                     [PC2]
```

`VPN CLIENT` can access shares from `PC1` and `PC2`, but **not** from `VPN HOST PC`

This is my VPN host configuration:

[image: VPN host configuration]

The IP range is outside the DHCP pool.  Is there some other configuration I need to apply for this to work or is this just a limitation of Windows' built-in VPN service?

**EDIT**: worth noting, I can't ping the VPN host from the VPN client either.

Comment: Are you accessing the remote share by UNC, FQDN or IP (or have you tried them all)?

Comment: @Kinnectus: yes, I tried them all.  I can't even ping the host from the client, but I can ping other clients on the host network.